# JavaScript How to replace first element of an array with each element of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have two arrays and I need to replace the first element of the first array with each elements of the second array:

```
let firstArray = [
  [1, 'a', 'hello'],
  [2, 'b', 'world'],
  [3, 'c', 'other'],
  ...
];

let secondArray = [1, 3, 7, ...];

// Result: 
// [
//  [1, 'a', 'hello'],
//  [3, 'b', 'world'],
//  [7, 'c', 'other'],
//  ...
// ]
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
firstArray.map(f => {
  secondArray.forEach(s => {
      f.splice(0, 1, s);
  })
})
```

But this replace the first element only with the last element of second array

Comment: Also, post your expected output to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map` to transform an array into another:

```js
const firstArray = [
  [1, 'a', 'hello'],
  [2, 'b', 'world'],
  [3, 'c', 'other'],
];

const secondArray = [1, 3, 7];

const transformed = firstArray.map(([, ...rest], i) => [secondArray[i], ...rest]);
console.log(transformed);
```

Another option:

```js
const firstArray = [
  [1, 'a', 'hello'],
  [2, 'b', 'world'],
  [3, 'c', 'other'],
];

const secondArray = [1, 3, 7];

const transformed = firstArray.map((item, i) => [secondArray[i]].concat(item.slice(1)));
console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the array to a new array and take the new value to a specified index.

```js
const
    firstArray = [[1, 'a', 'hello'], [2, 'b', 'world'], [3, 'c', 'other']],
    secondArray = [1, 3, 7],
    result = firstArray.map((a, i) => Object.assign([], a, { 0: secondArray[i] }));

console.log(result);
```